# vectorization of dj_db vs for loop

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am working on learning multiple linear regression from the coursera course by andrew i think.

the examples for dj_db in its lab could be done simpler in my opinion and i really want to understand this before moving on.

this is what was provided in the compute_gradient function

```
for i in range(m):                             
        err = (np.dot(X[i], w) + b) - y[i]   
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err * X[i, j]    
        dj_db = dj_db + err                        
dj_dw = dj_dw / m                                
dj_db = dj_db / m
```

Im not concerned with the dj_dw yet.

I figured this could be done simply with

```
dj_db = (np.sum((np.dot(X, w) + b) - y)) / m
```

but this gives a different output, even though they look functionally the same.

heres the full function in case its helpful.

```
def compute_gradient(X, y, w, b): 
    """
    Computes the gradient for linear regression 
    Args:
      X (ndarray (m,n)): Data, m examples with n features
      y (ndarray (m,)) : target values
      w (ndarray (n,)) : model parameters  
      b (scalar)       : model parameter
      
    Returns:
      dj_dw (ndarray (n,)): The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameters w. 
      dj_db (scalar):       The gradient of the cost w.r.t. the parameter b. 
    """
    m,n = X.shape           #(number of examples, number of features)
    dj_dw = np.zeros(n)
    dj_db = 0.

    for i in range(m):                             
        err = (np.dot(X[i], w) + b) - y[i]   
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err * X[i, j]    
        dj_db = dj_db + err                        
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m                                
    dj_db = dj_db / m
        
    return dj_db, dj_dw
```

(sorry if this is not the right format. I havent used this much)

Comment: i'd stick with the original code given in the Jupyter notebooks. Note that it calculates `err` once (and this is a nontrivial calculation -- the matrices can be huge) and then uses the result over and over in the loop (which loops over `j`, not `i`) and also to calculate dj_db for each i.

Comment: Have you tried this?  The issue is that `X` is 2D while `w` is 1D, and the `np.dot` doc tells you that does a sum/product on the last axis or `X`.  I'd have to use pencil and paper to decide if that works here.

Comment: @S.Imp it doesnt calculate it once, it calculates it for every sample given and sums them right? that should be the same?

Comment: @TimRoberts ill have to try some simpler numbers and test where the difference lies. i thought i understood it well enough.

Comment: @HestonVaughan you yourself said it was returning the wrong value. I was pointing out that, while it's tempting to cram all the calculation in one line, thinking you are 'vectorizing the calculation,' err is a painful calculation, so you'd want to avoid calculating its value any more than you had to. Calculating it once per loop iteration will be more efficient than your clever line to calculate dj_db. I haven't worked through the values getting returned. It also occurred to me that this might be a related to the simultaneous update requirement.

Answer (score 0):

after some simple testing I realized my simple mistake. They DO return the same thing. I was testing inside the function and was not resetting it to 0 after using the same variable name, so it was summing on top of my answer....

```
def compute_gradient(self, X, y):
    m,n = X.shape
    dj_dw = np.zeros(n)
    dj_db = 0.

    err = (np.dot(X, self.w) + self.b) - y
    for i in range(m):                             
        for j in range(n):
            dj_dw[j] = dj_dw[j] + err[i] * X[i, j]                      
    dj_dw = dj_dw / m
    dj_db = np.sum(err) / m
    return dj_db, dj_dw
```

This code works as expected and returns what the lab function does.
Apologize for that! thanks for the help. I tested for over an hour and did not notice.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but it looks to me like this violate the simultaneous update/assignment requirement. I think it might also be less efficient than the original code because you are repeating a lot of the calculations performed on these large matrices/vectors. It might not be noticeable on the small examples, but if you were performing it on a dataset with 2000 features and 5000 samples, you'd certainly notice it.

Comment: @S.Imp youre exactly right, there was some redundant code there. That was only because i was trying to see the difference, and in messing with the code messed it up and didnt realize. Thats why i was getting two different values. The for loop and the np version do the same thing.

Also, this function returns the gradient, and then you use that to update the ws and b

Comment: @S.Imp I have since updated the code in my answer. It now shows the function i wrote that returns the same thing as the lab, i was able to successfully train the model with it. It's shorter and makes much more sense to me. Let me know if you can see anything wrong with it

Comment: I confess I haven't tested your code with actual numbers, nor do I profess to know if its absolutely correct or not. I note that your code requires an err[i] lookup in your innermost loop. I think array lookups like that are pretty efficient in python but they can be expensive in other languages. Your code must perform this err[i] lookup i*j times, which could easily be in the millions. I'd be curious how fast your function is compared to that from the course materials. I suspect the latter is still faster.

Comment: @S.Imp just now seeing this. I see what youre saying, but the reason i disagree is it not only makes the code easier to read, but it uses numpy arrays which use parallel processing, so from my understanding it shouldnt add to the time. also you have the benefit of only calculating err once.

Comment: your err calculation puts i values in a big data structure-- your `err` vector--and then with each iteration of your *innermost* loop, your code looks up the ith slot inside this big data structure. You are performing that lookup far too often -- a total of i * j times-- and this might be more expensive than whatever gain you get by calculating every err value at once. You are performing that lookup `j` more times than you should, and should at least move the lookup outside the innermost loop. Also, I'm not sure I agree that your approach is more readable.

Comment: @S.Imp Ah, I think I may understand. it calculated err i times, but doesnt have to look it up at all, only use the variable. That does sound more efficient. Ill try to do some more research on that. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: There is, in fact, a small penalty to look up a value inside an array/vector/matrix. It takes more time to find the `ith` element of some vector, `err`, than it does to simply check some scalar variable. I expect these array lookups are pretty efficient in python, but I know from experience that they are slow in PHP. I'd strongly suggest that you compare the performance of the original code from your assignment against your altered function on a **large** data structure. It won't be noticeable if i and j are small, but if there are large (e.g. 10,000) it might matter.